# How to create a table that updates correctly when I add values to a firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

The current solution that I have displays the data correctly when I load the screen, but when I add a value via the input from my HTML page it duplicates the table values and includes the new value. When I refresh the page there aren't any duplicates anymore. I'm not too sure how to approach another solution. Is there a way to create a new table that replaces the old one every time something is added to the database? Or is there a way to add to the old table somehow?

[This is the table when I first load the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRl9E.png)

[This is the table after I added the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpA5d.png)

Here is my html code for the table

```
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Shots Attempted</th>
      <th scope="col">Shots Made</th>
      <th scope="col">Percentage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my js that calls the firebase database values and adds them to the table

```
var query = rootRef.orderByKey();
let table = document.getElementById('table-body');
query.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    const key = childSnapshot.key;
    const childData = childSnapshot.val();
    let table = document.getElementById('table-body');
    const row = `<tr>
                <td>${key}</td>
                <td>${childData.shotsM}</td>
                <td>${childData.shotsA}</td>
                <td>${childData.shotsP}</td>
              </tr>`

    table.innerHTML += row
  })
})
```

Comment: Add `table.innerHTML = "";` outside the iteration. BTW You declare the let table twice?

Comment: I was experimenting and forgot to take one of them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On *value* updates, empty the `<tbody>`
2. Iterate the new values and add them to the table

```js
var query = rootRef.orderByKey();
let table = document.getElementById('table-body');
const cells = ['shotsM', 'shotsA', 'shotsP']

// just a simple tag creator utility
const createTag = (tagName, textContent, props) =>
  Object.assign(document.createElement(tagName), { textContent }, props)

query.on('value', dataSnapshot => {
  table.innerHTML = '' // empty the <tbody>
  dataSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
    const key = childSnapshot.key
    const childData = childSnapshot.val()

    // create a new row
    const tr = createTag('tr')
    // create a cell for the "key"
    const keyCell = createTag('td', key)

    // add all the cells to the new row
    tr.append(keyCell, ...cells.map(cell => createTag('td', childData[cell])))

    // add the row to the table
    table.append(tr)
  })
})
```

You don't have to use the DOM methods like `document.createElement()` but I just find it much cleaner than working with strings of HTML.

Comment: Moving the table.innerHTML = ' ' above the forEach worked when I added it to my solution. Your solution also works I just had to change the last line to table.append(tr).

Comment: Good catch. Fixed now 